# hdb parameter definition header file difference with .h files

Tags: c, header, embedded

What is the difference between .hdb header files for parameter declaration and regular .h header files?

Comment: I've never seen the `.hdb` extension before. Where have you come across it?

Comment: it is not clear what is HDB header and from where it is comming...